# There are $2n$ red dots and $2n$ blue dots on a paper. Prove that there exists $2n$ non-intersecting line segments joining red and blue dots.

Tags: combinatorics

> There are $2n$ red dots and $2n$ blue dots on a paper. Prove that there exists $2n$ non-intersecting line segments joining red and blue dots. No three dots are collinear.

---

$\textbf{My approach:}$ No matter how the red and blue dots are located we can always form a quadrilateral using 2 blue points and 2 red points. However there can be 2 variations of this quadrilateral. The first one is this:
[image]

where the same colored dots are on same side, thus giving us 2 such non intersecting lines.
The second formation of quadrilateral is this:
[image]

Here we can see we are getting 2 pairs non intersecting segments [$BC$ with $AD$, $BD$ with $AC$],  hence a total of 4 such lines. Now this is where I'm stuck because I don't know which of these 2 quadrilateral there are going to be, which would affect the total number of non-intersecting lines. How do I proceed?

Comment: I don’t think this is correct. We can plot the red and blue points so that they are all collinear, say with all the reds on the ‘left’ side and all the blues on the ‘right’. There is one line connecting red to blue: all other such lines must intersect the first line!

Comment: I assume you forgot to mention that no three points are collinear, right?

Comment: @lulu yes it was given that no 3 are collinear. let me add that to the post